# Convert NSNumber to int

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

EDIT: Revision of question, narrowed the scope

I need to use a switch statement to direct outcomes based on the int value of an NSNumber. My method looks like this:

```
-(BOOL)setImage:(NSNumber*)c{
       switch ([c intValue]){...}
}
```

I get a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error on the switch when I run it

I have also tried `switch([c integerValue])` but that doesn't work either

If I place a static int in the switch statement, the program runs fine.

What's wrong and how can I get the int value of my NSNumber?

Comment: If `activeColors` is `nil` or is empty, you will get a division by zero. Add `NSLog(@"%d", [activeColors count])` to check.

Comment: the log outputs 2, which is expected

Comment: Well can't you set [activeColors count] as a static int then calculate a random index?

Comment: no, activeColors size will fluctuate

Comment: Something else must be going on that we cannot see here. Add `NSUInteger count = [activeColors count]; NSUInteger n = arc4random() % count;`, and run this through a debugger.

Comment: Something else was happening but I don't know what.. I separated it out into more statements and it ran fine, then I put it back together into one statement and it still ran fine - I was rebuilding the project everytime I ran so I have no idea why that happened.. The program still doesn't run though - its hung up on a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `[c intValue]` crashes then `c` isn't an object pointer.  If it returns an unexpected value, it's probably `nil`.  It is a good idea to check for that, and either return `NO` for `nil` numbers or choose some default value.

Comment: Yeah, one of my subclasses was passing the function an int instead of an NSNumber

Comment: Unless I'm misreading your comment, it's not completely correct. Sending a message that should return a primitive object to nil is just as valid as sending a message that should return an object. In other words, sending _any_ message to nil is always OK. On the other hand, sending a message to a non-object other than nil will crash, and it sounds like that's @Cbas's problem.

Comment: I will edit the question to be a bit clearer, but it's basically never a safe thing to do when primitive types are involved.  If the method is supposed to return a data structure such as `NSRect` it will *definitely* crash when called on `nil` objects.  If it's a primitive type, you might get 0 (for an integer) or whatever happened to be in the FPU for a floating-point value, etc. but certainly nothing sensible.

Comment: That's not exactly true either. The following code compiles and runs without crashing on my machine: `NSValue *test = nil; NSLog(@"value %@", NSStringFromRect([test rectValue]));` The output is "value {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}". Additionally, Apple's Objective-C Programming Language Reference is explicit in saying that sending a message that returns a struct to nil is OK, although depending on the struct, the value of some fields may be undefined. Reference here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html (Sending Messages to nil)

Comment: @AndrewMadsen I can't reproduce the crashing behavior that I thought I'd seen in the past (at least not with GCC) so I've removed that claim.  Thanks for pointing it out and referring to documentation.

Comment: You had me double checking myself, which is always good :-). +1 for your answer.

Comment: Well, I double-checked too so thank you. :)  If I didn't see this exact behavior, I certainly saw something very close to it in the past.